# Sending email in Pardot Engagement Studio using dynamic list during business hours

Tags: email, list, pardot

There is a program in Pardot Engagement Studio having 3 simple steps - start/entry point - a dynamic list, send email, end. The email is to be send on weekdays during business hours.

The dynamic list (entry point) keeps on changing on daily basis. Now say there are 10 prospects in the list which got added to the program, by the time the business hours starts, the list gets updated now those 10 earlier prospects are not there, instead there are other/new 5 prospects. In this case the program won't send the email to those 10 prospects as they are not there in the list.

What is the way around? Can't keep the prospect in the dynamic list beyond a certain point.

Answer (score 0):

Use a segmentation rule to put them on a static list and use that static list to drive the Engagement Studio.